# UI messed up when returned to app after click on home button

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I have an iPad app. When the app is running, I click on home button. When I again open the app, UI is messed up. I have a method which takes care of my UI and which arranges all my targets. Is there any place where in I can invoke this method when I open my app after pressing home button ? Can I use this method ?

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That method is there for this.

According to doc,

> you could also use it to refresh your application’s user interface.

In addition, you can also register for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification. This is called after the previous method.

If you provide some other details, we can help you.

Cheers.